# Sending and Formatting Variable Through HTTP

Tags: python, http

Hey so I have been trying to make a script that just reads the amount of followers someone has and then send the amount of followers back to the server that requested it. I have absolutely no idea how http works or how to properly format a variable to go across it. Whenever I make a request I get a bad response error. I know what is causing this, it’s the variable and how python formats it, but how would I send this over http? Any help? (Also this server won't have very much traffic at all)

````
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import http
import http.server
import socketserver
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import json
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

class requestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers
        
        print(self.path[1:])
        driver.get('https://www.tiktok.com/@%s?lang=en' % self.path[1:])
        FOLLOWERS = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/header/h2[1]/div[2]/strong').text
        driver.close
        print(str(FOLLOWERS))
        self.wfile.write((str(FOLLOWERS).encode()))
        
def main():
    PORT = 8000
    server = HTTPServer(('', PORT), requestHandler)
    print('Server running on port %s' % PORT)
    server.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()```
````

Comment: Have you tried printing the URL you’r creating for `driver.get()` so you can check the formatting or try opening the URL in a browser?

Comment: I get the follower count correctly, but I just do not know how to send a variable over http

Comment: What do you see in your browser? Or, what error message do you get from your Python code?

Comment: I get "ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE",

Comment: did you run code in console to see error message ? It should shows  where is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to create a function call when ending the header.

```
self.end_headers()
```

is what you want (the round brackets are missing). otherwise, chrome won't recognize this as a valid HTTP response.
Interestingly, this code works when using firefox.

Comment: And there may be a similar problem with `driver.close` - should be `driver.close()`?